# What is the best query to retrieve the top N highest id from SQL table - The efficent query as possible

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say there is a table of customers, each customer in this table has an id which is PK (integer).
What is the most efficient way to write a query that returns the 3rd highest id?
And I in here presume it's 3rd, but my intention is for N highest.
I wrote two queries and I wonder which one is better?

```
    select top 1 Customer_Id
    from customers c
    where c.Customer_Id not in(
        select top 2 cc.Customer_Id
        from customers cc
        order by cc.Customer_Id desc
        )
    order by c.Customer_Id desc
    ------------------------------
    select top 1 temp.Customer_Id
    from (
          select top 3 c.Customer_Id
          from customers c
          order by c.Customer_Id desc) as temp
    order by temp.Customer_Id
```

If someone here has a better approach, I will be glad to hear.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` or `OFFSET` are likely contenders, if I am honest.

Comment: Just use OFFSET...FETCH if you aren't on some ancient version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#Offset

Answer (score 3):

Just use an `OFFSET`, like I mentioned:

```sql
DECLARE @N int = 3; --Demonstrates that the OFFSET can be parametrised

SELECT CustomerID
FROM dbo.Customer C
ORDER BY CustomerID DESC
OFFSET @N-1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Though I can't prove it, the fact  @חייםחדד 's reputation dropped by 1 immediately afterwards suggests that they are the one that downvoted; I would appreciate hearing their thoughts on why this isn't useful so I can improve it. Thanks.

Comment: They have [lost a total of 6 points](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9157013/%d7%97%d7%99%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%97%d7%93%d7%93?tab=reputation&sort=time) on this question from downvoting. The earliest downvote is linked to a different Answer; the newest downvote entry (for four points) is not linked to a specific Answer. I think you're right, @Larnu.

Comment: Like I said, I have nothing to prove it @RossPresser , it *might* be coincidence. On the other hand, I haven't voted on this page at all (even though the OP has received 3 downvotes). Though a little odd, their answer isn't not useful; it'll do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using the Row_Number function to list them in order, giving you the ability to select the nth number:

```
DECLARE @TargetRowNum INT = 2;
WITH CustomerList
AS (
SELECT c.Customer_Id
    , CustomerRowNum = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY c.Customer_Id ORDER BY c.Customer_Id DESC)
FROM customers c
)
SELECT *
FROM CustomerList
WHERE CustomerList.CustomerRowNum = @TargetRowNum;
```

Comment: Why not, @חייםחדד ?

Comment: Shouldn't have a PARTITION

Answer (score 0):

According to @Larnu, I hope this could be a solution:

```
    select temp2.Customer_Id
    from(
        select temp.Customer_Id, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by grp order by temp.Customer_Id desc) as rrank
        from (
             select c.Customer_Id, 1 as grp
              from customers c  
             ) as temp
    ) as temp2
    where temp2.rrank = 3
```

Comment: Why `PARTITION BY` on a arbitrary number and not just omit the `PARTITION BY`  (and the subquery used to create said arbitrary number)?

Comment: Why do you "hope"? You look at the execution plans to answer any real question about performance. There are no absolute answers that apply universally.